# How to pass the name of a class variable to a function?

Tags: python

I've got a class, like so:

```
class Student:
    self.name
    self.email
    self.age
    self.ssn
```

I want to create a function outside the class that can receive one of the class variables as an argument, so something like this:

```
def print_all_vars(list_of_objects, class_var):
    for obj in list_of_objects:
        print obj.class_var

print_all_vars(students, name)
print_all_vars(students, ssn)
```

... and if this code worked it would print all the names of the students followed by all the ssn numbers.

However, I'm not trying to pass the data inside `name` and `ssn`, just the actual variable names. Obviously using the strings "name" and "ssn" aren't solutions.

Is this even possible? If so how could I implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin method `getattr` to do this. Here's `print_all_vars` with `getattr`.

```
def print_all_vars(list_of_objects, class_var):
    for obj in list_of_objects:
        print getattr(obj, class_var)
```

Just note that to use it, `class_var` has to be a String (e.g. `print_all_vars(students, "name")`).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks a bunch.